# Error: $digest already in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm getting this error while trying to call

```
        function MyCtrl1($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
      $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
        if (answer) {
          $location.url($location.url(next).hash());
          $rootScope.$apply();
        }
      });
    }

MyCtrl1.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope'];
```

Error is

```
Error: $digest already in progress
```

Comment: This is a very old post, but still you can refer to this post: http://www.boynux.com/angularjs-apply-explained/ I tried to explain $digest in progress very simple.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Duplicated: [Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)**

That error you are getting means Angular's dirty checking is already in progress.

Most recent best practices say that we should use `$timeout` if we want to execute any code in the next *digest* iteration:

```
$timeout(function() {
  // the code you want to run in the next digest
});
```

---

**Previous response:** ([don't use this approach](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns))

Use a safe apply, like this:

```
$rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply();
```

Why don't you invert the condition?

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {                
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: updated my whole code...its not showing the error now but its not serving the purpose, to go to next view

Comment: Does it pass the `if (answer) {` condition? What's the content from `next`?

Comment: Do you get any error on the console? Is there any HTTP request going out?

Comment: To prevent JS lint errors, use this: if (!$scope.$$phase) {
 $scope.$apply();
 }

Comment: According to the project, you shouldn't use $$phase becaus it's going away in the future and will break your code. http://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns 
Instead, just wrap anything you think needs a safe apply inside a $timeout. It will safely apply after the current digest cycle.

Comment: Use `$timeout()`. It has an implied $apply that executes on the next digest cycle.

Comment: try with    if(!$scope.$$phase) {}

Answer (score 13):

For others looking to troubleshoot this error, it's worth noting that the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog) seem to suggest using the `$timeout` service to ensure the code will be called in a single `$apply` block.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.someData = someData;
});
```

Also discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply?lq=1) if you look past the accepted answer.

Comment: i was getting same error but using just this code solved this.can you please tell me how does this worked?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$scope.evalAsync(function(){ 
});
```

instead of

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
});
```

Comment: It worked , but i had to use $scope.$evalAsync(function(){ 
});

Answer (score 2):

josliber's answer solved a similar $digest problem that I was having. I just used

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function(){ 
   // code here
});
```

Good article here
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 0):

Because your $scope.$apply() is inside **AngularJs environment**.In general I will not suggest you to use $apply(), moreover of $rootScope.$apply() functions make your application run slowly.It runs a new cycle of your whole scope.