# Angular make a resquest after a response server

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying make a server call after a response server like this

```
 $http.post($scope.serviceSave, {
            'person': $scope.person
        }).success(function(data){
            $http.get($scope.serviceList);
        });
```

but when I tried it I got

```
Error: $digest already in progress
```

and didn't made the request.

I'm tring using jquery like this

```
<a href="#" ng-click="setContent('/people/list')" >People</a>

$scope.setContent = function(service){
            $http.get(service);
}
```

then

```
 $http.post($scope.serviceSave, {
            'person': $scope.person
        }).success(function(){
            $("a:contains(People)").click();
        });
```

I can make the request, forcing click, but I'm getting

```
Error: $digest already in progress
```

yet

please, What's the correct form?

Comment: Have you tried using angular? promise-resolve mechanism ? (http://www.egghead.io/video/o84ryzNp36Q)

Comment: dosen't work I try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/angularjs-processing-http-response-in-service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838184/error-digest-already-in-progress

Comment: Thanks mb21, is there any form to do it automatically?... like a trigger after end the first request?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this in `JsFiddle` and could not do that. It looks like calling one request in callback of another is perfectly valid. Are you using `$http` service for each request? Not doing so is asking for trouble.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeConstructors/KcDQ4/) (keep in mind I'm addressing mocked services there, which might be a factor):

```
$http.post("/echo/json/").success(function() {            
        console.log("finished 1st");
        $http.get("/echo/json/").success(function() {
            console.log("finished 2nd");
        });
});
```

However calling one callback from within another callback is considered a bad practice. As mentioned before (by someone), using deferred is much more better:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var promise = deferred.promise;

$http.post("/echo/json/").success(function() {            
    console.log("finished 1st");
    deferred.resolve();            
});

promise.then(function(){
    $http.get("/echo/json/").success(function() {
        console.log("finished 2nd");
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeConstructors/KcDQ4/1/) for example above: