# Error: $digest already in progress in angularjs when using alert

Tags: angularjs

I am just getting the json data from the services in the controller.

And I am using a callback function to print the success message when it got loaded. It is working fine but it is also throwing an error which I mentioned in the question

```
//JSON file
{
"pc":"name"
}

// angular services
var service = angular.module('Services', ['ngResource']).
factory('Widgets', function($resource){
    return $resource('/json/home.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false}
    });
});

//controller
function editWidget($scope, Widgets) {
 $scope.data = Widgets.query(function(data) {   
    alert("Success Data Loaded ---> " + JSON.stringify(data.pc));
 });
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code - your problem must lie elsewhere. You usually get this error message when you do a `$scope.$apply(...)`

Comment: Is the alert failing? How about using a console.log to see the value of the json if the alert gives you problem?

Comment: @BoxerBucks yes when i am using console.log it is not throwing the error. but i just wanted to know the cause of the error.

Comment: Here is the working proof of no bug in your code:  http://plnkr.co/edit/YDsjQIkBj9JtTZn3V4qX?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: $digest already in progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838184/error-digest-already-in-progress)

Comment: you can use this link [error $digest] for i worked perfect 


[error $digest]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838184/error-digest-already-in-progress

Comment: You can refer to this post: http://www.boynux.com/angularjs-apply-explained/ I tried to explain $digest in progress very simple.

Answer (score 12):

`alert`, as well as `confirm` and `prompt` will pause the execution of code (blocks the thread), during which timeouts and intervals go all haywire if they should have been triggered during the pause.  The `$digest` loop is made up of two smaller loops, which process `$evalAsync` queue and the `$watch` list.  The `$evalAsync` queue is used to schedule work which needs to occur outside of current stack frame, but before the browser's view render. This is usually done with `setTimeout(0)`.  Your alert during this time causes the problem.

Comment: This is definitely the problem but is there a solution beyond not using alert?

Comment: Use non-blocking alerts (modals).  you can even override window.alert to call your modal.  You can also style the modal alerts and can look better than native alerts.

Answer (score 10):

You can use $timeout to execute an alert after the digest cycle is done and this way avoids this error.

```
$timeout(function () {
    alert('Alert text');
 });
```

Also don't forget to inject $timeout into your directive

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!confirm('Your message')){
  return false;
}else {
  return false;
}
```

Return false in both cases.

Answer (score -2):

@TheSharpieOne is right, It's work for me.

```js
function delayalert(messagestr){
           setTimeout(function(){
                alert(messagestr);
            },0);
}
```