# Why is the view not updating in this particular case? ($scope.$apply)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just trying to understand why in this case I would need to use $scope.$apply ? According to all the info I've read about the subject, I shouldn't have to, since everything is happening inside Angular? What am I missing?

In my controller:

```
$scope.savePreset = function(columns, $event){
  $event.preventDefault();
  preset.name = prompt("Please enter preset name", "My Preset");
  if (preset.name != null) {
    preset.columns = $scope.columns;
    $scope.presets[preset.name] = preset; // (Object)
    // Without $scope.$apply() here, view isn't updated. Why?
    alert('Your preset "' + preset.name + '" has been saved.');
    $scope.loadPreset(preset.name);
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a valid name.');
  }
}
```

(the `savePreset` function is called in an ng-click directive, and there's an ng-repeat for `preset in presets`, which isn't updating).

Thanks,
Pim

Comment: could you post example in jssfidle ?

Comment: It's because of `prompt`. Here's an identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351184/error-digest-already-in-progress-in-angularjs-when-using-alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in comment  @Sergiu Paraschiv using functions which wrapped in `window` was stopping angular `$digest` cycle that's why my advise is to use `$window` provider and `$window.prompt` and $window.alert functions I think they are will work

[here is a example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TOedJAG5NkSMpsRUMRVB?p=preview)

Comment: I will mark this one as answered since you're also providing a workaround, thanks.

Comment: since you marked my answer, I will share it also in twitter ) its actually interesting question

Answer (score 1):

~Prompt, alert.. will pause the execution of code (blocks the thread),  to prevent the likes of setInterval, setTimeout to go crazy .

The $digest loop is made up of two smaller loops:
 when you do a prompt. $evalAsync is used, and the code inside is executed outside angular.This is usually done with setTimeout(0).

So In one sentence: this is prompt's fault, you might be better off with a widget that does the same thing.

Edit:
Sorry submitted to fast: here is the original answer:
[Error: $digest already in progress in angularjs when using alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351184)

Comment: You just copied the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351184/error-digest-already-in-progress-in-angularjs-when-using-alert At least link to it...

Comment: This is based of the same answer, but didn't know how to formulate it, so I summarized the article; but is submitted before editing it, thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: As long as you link to the original answer all is OK.

Comment: Now I'm not sure should I mark this as answered or not? :-) + @Sergiu Paraschiv was first, but in comment. Thank you both for the explanation, I suspected smthg like this.