# $digest already running - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, http, model-view-controller, angularjs

I want to "refresh" my view after some new data is loaded into my factory, but i cant figure out how to do this correctly.

```
$http.post(url, postKunde).success(function(data, status) {
                $rootScope.calc = data.calc;
                $rootScope.$apply();
        }).error(function(data, status) {
                console.log(status);
        });
```

This is the method Im using in my factory. And everytime it triggers i get this error:

```
Error: $digest already in progress
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly ? Thanks ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: $digest already in progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838184/error-digest-already-in-progress)

Comment: Can you just get rid of the `$rootScope.$apply()` call?

Comment: yeah but then the changes on the data don't apply on the view.

Comment: `$http` callbacks are wrapped in a call to `$apply()` (or they call `$apply`), so you shouldn't need to call `$apply()` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a safe apply that will check if there is a digest:

```
 $scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};
```

Reference for this little gem: https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma

Comment: Thanks that was a huge help !