# AngularJS back button

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on making an Android app using Phonegap and AngularJS. I'm attempting to create a button to be used as both a "cancel" and a "back" button, that will essentially just hit the browser's 'back' button.

Here's some sample HTML for the cancel button:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="goBack()" class="button--cancel weight--bold vertical-align--middle text-center">cancel</a>
```

And here is the controller for that page, with the goBack() button:

```
function NewOccasionCtrl($scope, $window) {
    $scope.$window = $window;
    $scope.goBack = function() {
      $window.history.back();
    };
}
```

This throws no errors, but also doesn't work... the emulator remains on the same page. Without the `$scope.$window = $window` it throws an error. I was hoping to achieve a functional 'back' button without having to create/use a directive, because as far as I understand those then implement templating and things I don't need/want.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: It makes no sense that $scope.$window = $window would be required.

Comment: @KarlZilles then it probably isn't required... like I said, this doesn't work and I'm a bit confused as to how to approach this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I went with using a Directive to make the back functionality reusable. Here is my final code:

HTML:

```
<a href back-button>back</a>
```

Javascript:

```
app.directive('backButton', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', goBack);

        function goBack() {
          history.back();
          scope.$apply();
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: When i use this code i get a '$digest already in progress' error

Comment: @PPPaul you can try using the strategy discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12859093/880859) to avoid that error

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue like this using phonegap and angular, $window.history.back() would not work. So  I created a workaround.

```
$scope.urlHistory = [];

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    if ($location.$$absUrl.split('#')[1] !== $scope.urlHistory[$scope.urlHistory.length - 1]) {
        $scope.urlHistory.push($location.$$absUrl.split('#')[1]);
    }
});

$scope.goBack = function () {
    $scope.urlHistory.pop();
    $location.path($scope.urlHistory[$scope.urlHistory.length - 1]);
};
```

Hope this help someone else.