# Why should I make $scope.$apply()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that make

`$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', somedata)`

from time to time. In controller I do

`$scope.$on('myEvent', function (evt, somedata) { $scope.data = somedata })`

The question is if I omit

`if (!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(); }`

in controller's event listener, then view won't change. Why is that? Is there any better way to do it?.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: From your code, you really don't need apply. Can you paste the entire code?

Comment: Sorry for late response, this is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/zr7asMrCZFEhufXhniy4?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because $apply is a lazy worker and will do the job only there is enough stuff to refresh. You can't control when, unless you explicitly call $scope.$apply.

Yes, there is a better way to do this : call safeApply. Because calling explicitly many $apply can cause conflicts. There is no official safeApply implementation, so can choose you poison :

- here : https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma
- or there : [AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)

Comment: Yes, I understand this. My question is why my view doesn't update when  I change the scope on message. 

`$scope.$on('message', function (e, data) {`

`  $scope.someData = data;`

`  // without this if view won't update`
`  if (!$scope.$$phase) {`
`    $scope.$apply();`
`  }`
`});`

Comment: I mean, why should I call `$apply` every time I got an event, that has been broadcasted from the `$rootScope`?

Comment: Yes, it falls in the scope where you have to call $apply. Don't call $apply all the time, but if there is such an unexpectable event (event from rootscope is one of them), then you'll have to call it anyway.