# $timeout not defined error in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
app.factory('Position', ['$timeout', function() {

    var position = {
        latitude: 44,
        longitude: 26
    };

    console.log("Timeout started");

    $timeout(function() {
        position.latitude += 15;
        position.longitude += 15;
    }, 2000);

    return position;
}]);
```

And I get `$timeout not defined` in Javascript console. Am I not injecting the dependency of the service correctly ?

Comment: Only tangentially related: if you have a build process, especially one using Grunt, you should check out `ngmin`. It will make your injectors minification safe and remove the burden of double typing. You'll only need the `function($timeout)`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You did not inject `$timeout`. It should be as follows.

```
app.factory('Position', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    ...
}]);
```

Declaration this way ensures that services are correctly identified when your JavaScript code gets minified. For further information on how this helps minification, see [A Note on Minification](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) and [Declaring AngularJS Modules For Minification](http://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification)

If minification is not in your plans (e.g for quick test), you can simply go with

```
app.factory('Position', function($timeout) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I believe with the built in services (anything with a $) you can just put them in the function sig, you don't have to declare them in the dependencies. If you are only using $ services that is.

Comment: I think it is done this way for minification purposes http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05