# Is there an equivalent to $scope.$apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing errors in Javascript because my $digest cycles are obviously all running at the same time.

Error I get : `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

I would like to know if I could use something in order to stop these cycles or maybe am I not defining my functions properly ?

Here is the code of my controller, as you can see there are two different $scope functions and the second one seems to be the problem :

```
.controller('accountController',['$scope', '$firebaseArray', 'CONFIG', '$document', '$state', function($scope, $firebaseArray, CONFIG, $document, $state) {
  // Create a reference to the file we want to download
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  console.log(userId);
  var database = firebase.database().ref('/accounts/' + userId);
  var storageRef = firebase.storage();
  var pathReference = storageRef.ref('/' + userId + 'profilepic.jpg');
  // Get the download URL
  pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.imageUrl = url;
      database.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var displayProfilePic = snapshot.val().photoURL;
  $scope.displayProfilePic = displayProfilePic;



  });

            });



  });
  var database = firebase.database().ref('/accounts/' + userId);
    database.on('value', function(snapshot) {
       var displayName = snapshot.val().name;
        var description = snapshot.val().description;
      var displayHobbies = snapshot.val().hobbies;
      var displayFacebook = snapshot.val().facebook;
      var displayTwitter = snapshot.val().twitter;
      var displayInstagram = snapshot.val().instagram;
      var displayYoutube = snapshot.val().youtube;
      var displaySnapchat = snapshot.val().snapchat;
      var displayLinkedin = snapshot.val().linkedin;
      var displayProfilePic = snapshot.val().photoURL;

         $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.displayName = displayName;
                        $scope.description = description;
            $scope.displayHobbies = displayHobbies;
            $scope.displayFacebook = displayFacebook;
            $scope.displayTwitter = displayTwitter;
            $scope.displayInstagram = displayInstagram;
            $scope.displayYoutube = displayYoutube;
            $scope.displaySnapchat = displaySnapchat;
            $scope.displayLinkedin = displayLinkedin;
            $scope.displayProfilePic = displayProfilePic;

            // Hide Social buttons if no value in Database :
            if (displayFacebook === "") {
              document.getElementById('iconFacebook').style.color = '#EFF1F5';
              var anchor = document.getElementById("linkFacebook");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
              var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
              att.value = "#";            // Set the value of the href attribute
              anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
            } else {
              document.getElementById('iconFacebook').style.color = '#80d5f2';
              var anchor = document.getElementById("linkFacebook");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
              var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
              att.value = "http://www.facebook.com/" + displayFacebook;            // Set the value of the href attribute
              anchor.setAttributeNode(att);                      // Add the href attribute to <a>
              };
              if (displayTwitter === "") {
                document.getElementById('iconTwitter').style.color = '#EFF1F5';
                var anchor = document.getElementById("linkTwitter");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                att.value = "#";            // Set the value of the href attribute
                anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
              } else {
                document.getElementById('iconTwitter').style.color = '#80d5f2';
                var anchor = document.getElementById("linkTwitter");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                att.value = "http://www.twitter.com/" + displayTwitter;            // Set the value of the href attribute
                anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                };
                if (displayInstagram === "") {
                  document.getElementById('iconInstagram').style.color = '#EFF1F5';
                  var anchor = document.getElementById("linkInstagram");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                  var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                  att.value = "#";            // Set the value of the href attribute
                  anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                } else {
                  document.getElementById('iconInstagram').style.color = '#80d5f2';
                  var anchor = document.getElementById("linkInstagram");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                  var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                  att.value = "http://www.instagram.com/" + displayInstagram;            // Set the value of the href attribute
                  anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                  };
                  if (displayYoutube === "") {
                    document.getElementById('iconYoutube').style.color = '#EFF1F5';
                    var anchor = document.getElementById("linkYoutube");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                    var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                    att.value = "#";            // Set the value of the href attribute
                    anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                  } else {
                    document.getElementById('iconYoutube').style.color = '#80d5f2';
                    var anchor = document.getElementById("linkYoutube");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                    var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                    att.value = "http://www.youtube.com/" + displayYoutube;            // Set the value of the href attribute
                    anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                    };
                    if (displaySnapchat === "") {
                      document.getElementById('iconSnapchat').style.color = '#EFF1F5';
                      var anchor = document.getElementById("linkSnapchat");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                      var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                      att.value = "#";            // Set the value of the href attribute
                      anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                    } else {
                      document.getElementById('iconSnapchat').style.color = '#80d5f2';
                      var anchor = document.getElementById("linkSnapchat");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                      var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                      att.value = "http://www.snapchat.com/" + displaySnapchat;            // Set the value of the href attribute
                      anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                      };
                      if (displayLinkedin === "") {
                        document.getElementById('iconLinkedin').style.color = '#EFF1F5';
                        var anchor = document.getElementById("linkLinkedin");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                        var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                        att.value = "#";            // Set the value of the href attribute
                        anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                      } else {
                        document.getElementById('iconLinkedin').style.color = '#80d5f2';
                        var anchor = document.getElementById("linkLinkedin");  // Get the <a> element with id="myAnchor"
                        var att = document.createAttribute("href");        // Create a "href" attribute
                        att.value = "http://www.linkedin.com/" + displayLinkedin;            // Set the value of the href attribute
                        anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
                        };

                });

    });

}])
```

Thank you for your advice !

**EDIT :** I use my app with tabs which I think are not stopping the cycles between each transition of screen ? Maybe ?

Comment: Why are you calling `$scope.$apply` when `pathReference.getDownloadURL` gets resolved?

Comment: Dear god, wrap your code in a function!

Comment: If the digest is already in progress, obviously it does not need to be started with $scope.$apply.

Comment: Hello guys, I am very new to Javascript and Ionic, so I try with tutorials online etc... I learnt what I could last week on Codecademy and so yes I have a lot of problems still. I would appreciate if you could show me a better way to organize my code and functions so I don't have to use the Scope one. I simply don't know any other way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always substitute `$scope.$apply` for either`$scope.$evalAsync` or `$timeout`. Below explains what each does:

`$scope.$evalAsync` - execute your callback inside the current digest cycle, or create a new one where no digest is running.

`$timeout` - wait for the current digest (if any) to finish and then run the callback in a new digest.

Hopefully this helps.

Tom

Comment: Hello, yes I tried both and each time I have this error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: $timeout is not defined`

Comment: You'll have to make sure you inject `$timeout` into your object - `function($scope, $timeout)` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009370/timeout-not-defined-error-in-angularjs-app)

Comment: Yes, I am aware :) it has all been entered properly and the error comes all the time. I am using Ionic 1 and there is literally NO function working except when you call with $scope.$apply, without it, you can not display anything in the DOM.

Comment: The answer I provided should work after all, under the hood they just call `$scope.$apply` ... Just at the correct time :-) something else must be awry.

Comment: Nevermind, I am an idiot. I wrote "$timeOut" all the time and it never worked. EDIT : THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0):

> ### Error: $rootScope:inprog
>
> ### Action Already In Progress
>
> **Description**
>
> At any point in time there can be only one `$digest` or `$apply` operation in progress. This is to prevent very hard to detect bugs from entering your application. The stack trace of this error allows you to trace the origin of the currently executing `$apply` or `$digest` call, which caused the error.
>
> **Digest Phases**
>
> AngularJS keeps track of what phase of processing we are in, the relevant ones being `$apply` and `$digest`. **Trying to reenter a `$digest` or `$apply` while one of them is already in progress is typically a sign of programming error that needs to be fixed. So AngularJS will throw this error when that occurs.**

The code **obviously** needs to be be fixed.

> **Diagnosing This Error**
>
> When you get this error it can be rather daunting to diagnose the cause of the issue. The best course of action is to investigate the stack trace from the error. You need to look for places where `$apply` or `$digest` have been called and find the context in which this occurred.
>
> There should be two calls:
>
> - The first call is the good `$apply`/`$digest` and would normally be triggered by some event near the top of the call stack.
> - The second call is the bad `$apply`/`$digest` and this is the one to investigate.
>
> Once you have identified this call you work your way up the stack to see what the problem is.
>
> If the second call was made in your application code then you should look at why this code has been called from within an `$apply`/`$digest`. It may be a simple oversight or maybe it fits with the sync/async scenario described earlier.
>
> If the second call was made inside an AngularJS directive then it is likely that it matches the second programmatic event trigger scenario described earlier. In this case you may need to look further up the tree to what triggered the event in the first place.

For more information, see [AngularJS inprog Error Reference -- Diagnosing This Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#diagnosing-this-error)