# Angular issue with nested ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I encounter an issue in Angularjs when using nested `ng-include` with the `$compile` function.
Here is the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- $anchorScroll <- ngIncludeDirective
```

I think, I have to inject the `$rootElementProvider` somewhere in the compile flow but I do not know how.

Here is a Plunker of my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/K8iayGXGLx5QwHNNiLZ1?p=preview

All the code is needed, and I can not use directives nor controllers, the templates also need to be cached like this. 
Furthermore, If someone also know how to get rid of the `$timeout` service to get through the`$digest` already running I will be really thankful.

Comment: Were you ever able to take care of this issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ? I am in the same situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're manually creating `$injector` you need to somehow tell it where to get `$rootElement` from. One way to do it is through inline module definition:

```
angular.injector(['ng', function($provide){
  var $rootElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));
  $provide.value('$rootElement', $rootElement);
}]).invoke(function ($injector){ 
    var localRootElement = $injector.get('$rootElement');
});
```

I've updated your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GWILwi9rNgQYnfcM3IhP?p=preview) accordingly.

As for a way to avoid using `$timeout` a detailed answer can be found in:

[Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply).

In short you can do a simple check (which does not mean you should):

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
}
```

Please refer to linked answer for more details.