# AngularJS: $rootScope.$watch not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the `$rootScope` to track favorites in my application, as they are modified I want to tell the application to update local storage to match.

In my controller I am using the following function to add / delete favorites:

```
$scope.toggleFavorite = function(product) {
    var item = {
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name
    }

    if (_.findWhere($rootScope.favoriteDrinks, item)) {
        console.log('Rootscope contains the item: Removing');
        $rootScope.favoriteDrinks = _.reject($rootScope.favoriteDrinks, function(favorite) {
            return favorite.id === item.id;
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Rootscope doesn\'t contain the item: Adding');
        $rootScope.favoriteDrinks.push(item);
    }

    console.log($rootScope.favoriteDrinks);
}
```

The `console.log()` produces expected results, it is updating and removing favorites as I add them throughout the application.

For the `$rootScope` I have the following code in my app.js`:

```
.run(['localStorageService', '$rootScope', function(localStorageService, $rootScope) {
    if (!localStorageService.get('favoriteDrinks')) { localStorageService.add('favoriteDrinks', []) };

    _.extend($rootScope, {
        favoriteDrinks: localStorageService.get('favoriteDrinks')
    });

    $rootScope.$watch('favoriteDrinks', function() {
        console.log('Favorite Drinks Modified');
    });
}]);
```

So on application startup, if the localstorage keys don't exist, I create empty ones, then extend the `$rootScope` to contain the favorites as retrieved from localStorage. Then I add the `$watch` to the `$rootScope`, however it is only firing the `console.log()` when I remove something from the `$rootScope`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you aren't removing from original array, you are creating a new array

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I am not sure what `_.reject(...)` do, but I think it is asynchronous.

To make the `$watch` statement works properly, we need to put the update statement to an asynchronous call. In your case, you should you $apply or $timeout.

Just try:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function () {
    $rootScope.favoriteDrinks.push(item);
});
```

or

```
$timeout(function () {
    $rootScope.favoriteDrinks.push(item);
});
```

Using `$timeout` maybe hack-ish, but it can avoid `$diggest already in process` problem.

More info about [$apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) and [$timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply).