# Is it always save to use $scope.$apply?

Tags: angularjs

Sometimes i need to use `$scope.$apply`, for example when i use jQuery ajax or some non-angular-js eventlisteners. In those cases i have an asynchronous callback and there i use `$scope.$apply` so that changes to the scope are picked up by angular and watches are triggered. Please correct me if that is the wrong use of `$scope.$apply`.

This seems to work and the view is updated. However in some rather rare cases I get a "digest already in progress" error. I don't see how this can be possible, since the callback is not synchronous. So I wonder if it is possible that my asynchronous callback with the `$scope.$apply` in it can by chance collide with an ongoing digest? If so, how can I prevent this from happening?

**edit:**

One possibility to check for a digest is checking $$phase: `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()` but this is an anti-pattern as the angularjs wiki says: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns

I want to fully understand why it is possible that I encounter a digest in an asynchronous callback. And why this is an antipattern.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you have jQuery AJAX and non-angular listeners floating around an Angular app? If it's old legacy code waiting to be updated, `$apply` is probably your best bet, but as you can see you run the risk of a digest already happening.

Comment: most of the time it's inside libraries I am using :/ another example is in phonegap i'm using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser where i want to listen to the load event of a new browser window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently asked a similiar question on why `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()` is an anti-pattern here: [Why is using if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply() an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346990/why-is-using-ifscope-phase-scope-apply-an-anti-pattern/22349659#22349659)

The answer there also contains the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `$apply` on an existing scope, so it's definitely possible that you are calling apply while it is currently digesting.  Some people might suggest checking $$phase but that has been discouraged as [an anti-pattern](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns)

You have two options if you are running into this problem, even occasionally.  One is to do as the anti-pattern implies and make sure your `$scope.$apply` is as high as possible up the chain.

However, this won't help if you are asynchronously calling `$apply` on the same $scope in rapid succession.  The answer then is often to [throttle](http://lodash.com/docs#throttle) the `$apply` so that it only happens every few hundred milliseconds.  This is a common practice when using something like `socket.io` that can fire events which could cause you to re-apply many times.

Comment: i already read that checking $$phase is an anti-pattern. But can you explain why and what do you mean by as high as possible up the chain? How exactly is it related to the "digest already in progress" error?

Comment: Since scopes are created in a hierarchy - eg: a controller in a controller, a directive not isolate scope - you could be calling $apply on a child scope while the parent scope is already digesting with that scope from some other change.  So your $apply should occur on the parent-most scope in those cases.  It still wouldn't fix it if you are directly calling $apply on that same scope before it has completed digesting. Does your $apply take a long time?  You could  debug with $$phase to see when it happens.  I suspect your async $apply calls are at times lagging very closely to each other.

Comment: thaks for your reply. I don't think those async calls are not close to each other but I cant't really say. One example is the geolocation plugin https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation (i haven't had a close look at how it uses apply yet) which threw me a digest error yesterday. As i understand i should use the rootScope to apply when possible to minimize potential digest errors. but often I cant't do this and there is always the possibility that a digest error occurs. right? so how do I completely eliminate that possibility? Using the anti-pattern?

Comment: You can certainly prevent it using a check for $$phase.  It shouldn't cause any issues but it's just masking a symptom.  However, if you've tried other fixes and it still happens rules were meant to be broken!

Comment: @matt-pileggi can you give an example of throttling the $apply as well as some citation of $$phase being an anti patern, when using event streaming it's something that people frequently run into and $$phase is almost always said to be the solution.

Comment: Sure, check out this article http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html and scroll down to "Optimizing the Digest Cycle" which deals with sockets in particular.  And the link in my answer has a short list of anti-patterns https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns

Answer (score 0):

I think, that its normal, but it will be better to move code to services and resources with angular style. To prevent error you can check current state

```
scope.$$phase
```

To prevent calling $apply

Answer (score 0):

Async Callbacks are an appropriate time to use the $apply, there are edgecases I have run into as well where i get that error.  They are usually because I am doing something wonky, I have found that a "Conditional Apply" works well for these.

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
}
```

[AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)

Comment: what do you mean by wonky and how does it cause a digest error?

Comment: When I have run into this in the past is was because I was using an eventing framework and multiple events where coming across the wire at near about the same time, so I would have code that handled an event and update the page then have another event come in and modify the data inside of an $apply and get the error.  Seemingly because angular was still in the process of digesting the last changes.