# angular + jquery event not binding after appending html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, grails

I searched on this issue too much here on stackoverflow, there were similar ones but none helpful and tried almost everything. **The problem is :**

I have an application in which I am using angular js to bind events like load more(pagination),"add to cart" etc etc .

**I am not using routes to load templates.** It is simply a grails application with ng-app in gsp and I am rendering template from server on ajax $http request.

When the page is loaded first time, view with model(data) is coming at once, so events are just working fine. But when I "load more" data with $http service and append to current DOM, event binding does not work. Even jquery click events are not working .

I am using this to bind data :

```
$('#itemsSpace').append($compile(response.data)($scope));

if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply() 
}
```

Where response is server response with html data.

Any guesses ? Any more explanations needed ?

Thanks!

Comment: do you bind to click events using ng-click directive or jquery .on() methods?

Comment: currently they are with ng-click directive and I want to work with only that as too many frameworks will just make mess . After appending html to current dom, ng-click does not work.

Comment: You need to append to the DOM first and then compile the DOM with the $scope.

Comment: Tip: don't do `if(!$scope.$$phase)`. It's bad. Use $timeout(function(){$scope.$apply()})` instead. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346990/why-is-using-ifscope-phase-scope-apply-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: Something like this `$('#itemsSpace').append(response.data);
   var doc = document.getElementById('itemsSpace');
   $compile(doc)($scope)
   $timeout(function(){$scope.$apply()})` . I did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $items = $(response.data);
$('#itemsSpace').append($items);

$compile($items)($scope);
```

EDIT:

Looking into the source of $compile, the compiler converts the given node into jQLite object if the node is not a jQLite instance. So, the OP's original code would work just as much as the code here. [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/VNL0OJ6sv4oUV6pePaV2?p=preview). The problem therefore lies somewhere else.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: but still events are not binding , not sure why if above way is the right way of doing so.

Comment: is there any way I can help with explanation ?

Comment: I just looked into it once again with fresh mid, problem was due to parent - child controllers . My  bad, load more was in parent controller and click was in child controller. binding scope to same controller where the click event is, fixed problem.