# View update issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On ajax call data receive, I am updating some part of page (listing of products)

```
$scope.posProducts = response.data_info.details.outletPrdData;
```

but my view is not getting update.
**View**

```
    <table style="display: block;">
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="posProduct in posProducts | filter:searchQueryForPOSProducts" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom:10px;">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:10px; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;" tooltip="Unit price : {{posProduct.prdUnitPrice}}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" ng:click="addItem(posProduct)">
                                    {{posProduct.prdName}}
            </button>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

When i tried to use $apply :

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
   $scope.posProducts = response.data_info.details.outletPrdData;
});
```

I am getting error:

```
$digest already in progress
```

**How i will update my page view on ajax call?**

It seems this problem is related to data binding.

I am using angularjs 1.2.16

Comment: Post the databinding code if you think that's where the problem is.

Comment: @AnthonyChu:Question is updated.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply

Comment: Any errors in console? What does `searchQueryForPOSProducts` look like?

Comment: log `response.data_info.details.outletPrdData` to the console. Remove your filter `| filter:searchQueryForPOSProducts` to test if that is interfering.

Comment: @JamesKleeh: But still i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem. I was updating wrong scope.

**The problem was because of my modal window scope and i need to update UI on `result.then` event of modal window.**