# AngularJS shows me "digest already in progress" after calling API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using AngularJS resource to call an API. When I get a list of items with the API, all shows well in my ng-grid. When I try to filter on for example employeename, angular returns me "digest already in progress". What could be the problem?

What I did to call the api is this:

```
'use strict';

angularApp.factory('absenceResource',['$resource',function($resource){
    var baseUrl = config.apiurl;
    var buildUrl = function(resourceUrl){
         return baseUrl + resourceUrl;
    };

    return $resource(buildUrl('api/absences/:employee'),
        {employee: '@employee'},
        {
            "update": {method: "PUT"}
        });
}]);
```

Then to call that resource:

```
'use strict';

angularApp.factory('absenceData',function(absenceResource, authService){
return{
    getAbsence: function(absenceId){
        return absenceResource.query({id: absenceId});
    },
    getAllAbsences: function(){
        return absenceResource.query();
    },
    getAllAbsencesForUser: function(user){
        return absenceResource.query({'employee': user});
    },
    update: function(absence){
        absenceResource.$update(absence);
    },
    save: function(absence){
        absenceResource.save(absence);
    }
};
```

Then in my controller I do this:

```
$scope.absencesForUser = absenceData.getAllAbsencesForUser("jurgen");

    //$scope.absences = absenceData.getAllAbsences();
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'absencesForUser'
    };
```

I then get the digest error.

I've searched for this problem, but all the problems that I've found had to do with $rootScope.apply and I don't use that.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question

Comment: Not sure where can come the problem, first let's trouble shoot it. Can you indicate which are exactly the offending files form your project? If you could isolate it in only a project with a couple of files or plunkr that would help a lot.

Comment: Can you try to use reource but just return the data on the success call of the reosource (you could use promises here), or just try  raw $http, let's check if it can be an issue of using resource

Comment: Can somebody help me with my plunker? I've put all the necessary files in the plunker, but get an unexpected token i error. My plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qwGkvNvz14UBFH8jUlD4?p=preview

Comment: Probably duplicate question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply