# How to re-calculate variable in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in (filteredItems = (clients | filter:searchText | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse))">
          ....
```

Controller:

```
function SomeController($scope，$http) {
    $http.get("http://www.example.com/someapi", function(data) {
        $scope.clients = data; // This code will cause a digest.
        waitUtilDigestEnd()  // I want to block it until the digest ends up so that $scope.filteredItems is up to date. How to write this code?
        handle($scope.filteredItems)
    })
}
function handle(filteredItems) {
   .....
}
```

My question is how to re-calculate filteredItems variable to make filteredItems contains newest data.

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. Calculate what? What is `handleFilteredData`?

Comment: once you get new value from service assign to clients and use $scope.$apply() it will rebind your data again

Comment: you can see clients is from ajax data, and filteredItems = (clients | filter:searchText | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse) in template.

Comment: The problem really is that you assign `filteredItems` in the view. Don't do this, and the solution becomes apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Since `loadAjax()`'s callback runs asynchronously, it will execute outside of the Angular context, meaning Angular will not know something changed.

In order for Angular to be aware of the changes, you should wrap your code in `$scope.$apply()`:

```
loadAjax('...', function (data) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.data = data;
        ...
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to call `handleFilteredData()` after the rest of the tasks have been completed, you can wrap it in `$evalAsync()`:

```
loadAjax('...', function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    ...
    $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
        handleFilteredData($scope.filteredItems);
    });
});
```

<sub>This approach doesn't seem to make much sense though, since `filteredItems` will change whenever the search-query or the sorting order changes and `handleFilteredData()` is not called for those cases. So, why do you want to handle `filteredItems` and not just handle `data` (unfiltered) ?</sub>

Comment: In fact, I use $http in function loadAjax, so angular knows the data is changed.  

after code $scope.clients = data; the digest begins to run, I need to know when the digest is finished so that we can run handleFilteredData($scope.filteredItems)

Comment: Because I want to export filtered data.

Comment: @Raymond: And what happens when the user changes the search query (and the filtered data changes) ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution at [AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)

```
$timeout(function() {
    // anything you want can go here and will safely be run on the next digest.
    handle($scope.filteredItems)
})
```