# AngularJS HTTP Call / Response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably something very simple but I am having some problem making an HTTP GET request, getting the data back, and attaching it onto the javascript global window variable.

Simple HTTP Call:

```
    $http.get("production/dashboard?dashboard_type=A").success((data) ->
      $scope.pods = data;

      window.pods = $scope.pods.to_json;
      window.type = 'A';

      alert(window.pods)
      alert(window.type)

      alert "success1"
      return
    ).error (data, status, headers, config) ->
      return
```

Upon execution, I am getting:

```
 1. Alert("undefined")
 2. Alert("A")
```

I thought that the promise of the http request will get resolved when the response returns?
I checked the Network tab and there is indeed JSON data being sent back as the response to the request.
I must be missing something simple...

Comment: Did you check what is `data.to_json` ?

Comment: `consle.log(data)` and you can inspect what came back

Comment: you have to get json data from $http .. can you something like $http.get('/products.json') in your scenario

Comment: Wow. Thanks guys. I forgot to get json data like @RahulSambari mentioned. I am getting the data now, but it seems I am getting a Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress now =O

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get("production/dashboard?dashboard_type=A")
     .success(function(data) {
      $scope.pods = data;

      window.pods = $scope.pods;
      window.type = 'A';

      alert(window.pods);
      alert(window.type);

      alert("success1");
      return
   }).error (function(data, status, headers, config){
            return;
     });
```

This is assuming it has access to the window where your code is.  Is this wrapped in a module and controller?

Comment: Yes. Apologies for the syntax, I was writing coffeescript. The module is in fact wrapped in a AngularJS Controller.

Answer (score 0):

As we need **json** data to get from $http.. Trying putting **.json** like below.

```
$http.get('/products.json')
```

Regarding your another issue.. you might get a hint with this link [AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)