# Change view from other javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are developing with angularjs and are running against a problem

We are changing views from inside the controllers normally, but in this case we need to change the view from an other js file.

What is the best way to tackle this?

We have created a method:

```
toShop: function() {
   var e = document.getElementById('appContainer');
        var scope = angular.element(e).scope();
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.toShop();
        }); 
    }
```

But this isn't working, the scope object is defined, but the apply function is not working.

Is there another way in angular to change views from outside the controller?

edit, controller code:

```
controllers.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.toShop = function() {
        alert('ruN!');
        $location.url('/shop');
    };
});
```

The first js should run the method of the second js

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example?

Comment: This is the code which is ran from the external js file.

Comment: any errors when you hit `f12`?

Comment: "apply already in progress"

Comment: k, i'm working on a plunkr 4 u. read - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18996042/3191896

Comment: please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/6A2a4GL7vPqB4fMhR8GW?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

So you got the famous `apply already in progress` error when you did `$apply`

best approach iv'e seen til this version of angular is to use `$timeout` which check if the apply is already running. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18996042/3191896))

var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $location, $timeout) {

   $scope.toShop = function() {
      alert('ruN!');
      $location.url('/shop');
    };

    $scope.toShopExternal = function() {
      $timeout($scope.toShop);
    };
  }
);
```

your external code

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#jquery-button").click(function() {
        var e = document.getElementById('appContainer');
        var scope = angular.element(e).scope();
        scope.toShopExternal();
      });
    });
  </script>
```

## http://plnkr.co/edit/opMH6jc0Ya1hKfSnsx7c?p=preview