# AngularJS - Cannot set scope value into template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have following function:

```
$scope.setDetailToScope = function(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        //$scope.order = data;
        $rootScope.order = data;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                //wrapped this within $apply
                $scope.order = data[0];
                console.log('message:' + $scope.order);
                console.log($scope.order);
            });
        }, 100);
    });
};
```

"

```
console.log($scope.order);
```

Gives me values which has been set into scope.

But i cannot get these values in template.

```
<!-- DEBUG DIV -->
<div class="debugDiv" ng-show="$root.debugable == true">
 {{columns}}
</div>
<div data-ng-controller="OrdersCtrl" ng-init="initData()"> 
    <div id="orders_grid" >

    </div>
</div>
<!-- GRID TOOLBAR BUTTON TEMPLATE -->
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <a class="k-button" href="\#/orders/create">Add</a>
</script>

<!-- ORDER DETAIL DIV -->
<div class="container" id="orderDetail" data-ng-controller="OrdersCtrl"  ng-if="'detailSelected == true'" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <!-- DEBUG DIV -->
    <div class="debugDiv" ng-show="$root.debugable == true">
      {{order}} <!--NOT WORKING-->
   </div>
```

If i tried to add values into rootscope it works, but in this case i cannot get value into ng-model.

What i'm doing wrong please?

Many Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

If i tried solution wit $timeout i got on console.log($scope.order);

following object which is not passed into the template:

```
_events: ObjectacrCrCode: "interlos"actionName: ht.extend.initarchived: falsebaseStationInfo: ht.extend.initbsc: "bsc1"btsRolloutPlan: "plan1"candidate: "B"costCategory: ht.extend.initcreatedBy: ht.extend.initdirty: falsefacility: ht.extend.initid: 3location: ht.extend.initmilestoneSequence: undefinednetworkType: "Fix"note: "poznamka"orderNumber: 111113orderType: ht.extend.initotherInfo: ht.extend.initparent: function (){return e.apply(n||this,r.concat(h.call(arguments)))}partner: ht.extend.initpersonalInfo: ht.extend.initproject: ht.extend.initpsidCode: "psid1"sapSacIrnCode: "sap1"uid: "924c0278-88d0-4255-b8ac-b004155463fa"warehouseInfo: ht.extend.init__proto__: i
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

well I'm not sure why you are using a setTimeout with scope apply, to me is safer to use a [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) since it fires another digest cycle,

try something like

```
$scope.setDetailToScope = function(data) {
    $timeout(funtion(){
        //$rootScope.order = data; try either data or data[0]
        $scope.order = data[0];

    },100);
};
```

please note that calling nested apply methods can run into some problems with the angularjs digest cycle you may get an error like "[digest already in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)" so put attention to it.

**NOTE:**

it seems like you got some dirty data there, so try to do a map between the data and the scope

```
$scope.order ={};
$scope.order.uid = data.uid;
$scope.order.orderNumber = data.orderNumber //and so on
```

in your template try something like:

```
 <div class="debugDiv">
     <p> {{order.uid}} </p>
     <p> {{ order.orderNumber}} </p>
   </div>
```

this could be a little bit rustic but it worth to try it out.

Comment: try either with data[0] or data, remove the ng-if you got in the details just for debugging purposes, try to do a console log and check what you got on the scope or rootscope

Comment: I tried you idea with static values, in console.log seems to be OK but nothing is displayed in template. But if i inserted some value into form inputs manually value appeared in the scope..is it strange.

Comment: do you have the elemens in the DOM? can you try to remove ng-if="'detailSelected == true'"  and also ng-show="$root.debugable == true" just for checking there's nothing to do with the conditions you are implementing for the dom