# Using a variable for ng-required doesn't re-evaluate fields

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where my intent is for required fields to not always be enforced. For example if the user is saving the document as a draft they can enter as little information as they like, if they try and publish the document then they have to enter all the required fields. I'm using a boolean on the controller which changes according to which button has been pressed e.g.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="field2" ng-required="enforceRequired" />
```

The problem is that the fields are not re-evaluated when the boolean changes so the form is submitted and then it becomes invalid. Please [see this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh9q00Le/13/) to see what I mean. If you fill in field1 and then click publish it will succeed on the first click and THEN become invalid.

How can I force the validation to run before the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yarons is right, you are changing the value too late, by late I mean after the form validations has been run. What you can do as a workaround is, after changing the `required` value, let angular do another cycle and then show your alert. This can be done via `$timeout` service, although I must mention that it is usually not a good practise to change the flow of your digest actions. It gets pretty messy pretty soon.

Change your publish function like this (and don't forget to inject $timeout)

```
$scope.publish = function () {
    $scope.enforceRequired = true;

    $timeout(function () {
        if ($scope.form.$valid) {
            alert("Published!");
        }
    });
};
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bh9q00Le/14/

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Thanks

Comment: This was the best solution I could find.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are changing the value of `enforceRequired` in the middle of the `digest` loop, so the watchers are not re-rendered before you check the input fields' validity (read about digest [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)).

If you want to get around it, I suggest one of the following methods:

1. change the value of `enforceRequired` before you call `saveDraft` or `publish`. see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/svhpdb8L/1/).
2. call `$scope.$apply()` after you change the value of `enforceRequired`. see [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/5az6cdca/).

Comment: $scope.$apply() was the best solution for me. Thanks very much.

Comment: I've actually just noticed that this causes errors in the console (Error: $apply already in progress). Is there any way around this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way around it. you can use [safe apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply), but it will cause the whole workaround not to work... That's why I suggested another approach.