# Ng-Repeat not updating after a Resource Query - $apply() is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem updating my view using ng-repeat that doesn't refresh after loading data from server using a query.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
vm.getPage = function() { 
            rendezvousResource.query(vm.gridOptions, function(result) {
                vm.gridData.totalItems = result.total;
                vm.gridData.totalPages = result.last_page;
                vm.gridOptions.page = result.current_page;
                vm.gridOptions.data = result.data;
                vm.rendezvouss = result.data;
                // $scope.$apply();
            });

        };
```

View :

```
        <table ng-controller="RendezvousListCtrl as vm"  class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Client</th>
                    <th>Date Début</th>
                    <th>Date Fin</th> 
                    <th>Type RDV</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Notification</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>  
                <tr ng-repeat="rendezvous in vm.rendezvouss">
                    <td>{{ rendezvous.nomClient }}</td> 
                    <td>{{ rendezvous.debut }}</td>
                    <td>{{ rendezvous.fin }}</td>
                    <td>{{ rendezvous.typerdv }}</td>
                    <td>{{ rendezvous.status }}</td> 
                    <td>{{ rendezvous.notification }}</td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I already tried to add $scope.$apply() but I get an : Error: error:inprog
Action Already In Progress

I already tried $timeout inside the callback function but it doesn't work, outside the function applying it on getPage it says undefined is not a function.

I also tried to use .then and $promise.then but it answers also undefined is not a function.

Any help please? :)

Comment: You do not need scope.$apply here. What do you see when you console.log(result.data) in the callback?

Comment: Write the handle of vm.getPage() function

Comment: @PSL I receive the data properly and I am able to put it in the vm.rendezvouss properly. The change is not triggered.

Comment: @rigobcastro the handler is ng-change of the pagination of ui.bootstrap

Comment: Write <pre>{{ vm | json }}</pre> and look what happen

Comment: it's binding pefectly and the data is updated....

Comment: I can't see the problem, I will change my structure to assign results directly to my model instead of putting result.data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply

Answer (score 0):

My Controller has been instantiated two times (my mistake) but this is what caused the ngRepeat to not refresh.

To be able to see this, I installed [AngularJS Batarang chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en). It offers a clean view of the scope and been able to see that my controller have been instantiated two times.