# AngularJS Stopwatch is unusably slow on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

So I wanted to make a stopwatch app that had some extra sports tracking features built in. I'm using this angular [timer](https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/) library for the stopwatch (with copied-from-the-docs start and stop buttons), then adding text to a list with a button- pretty straightforward.

```
var app = angular.module('myTimer', ['timer'])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.init = true;
  $scope.timerRunning = false;

  $scope.startTimer = function() {
    // calling init on a running timer borks it
    if ($scope.init) {
      $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
      $scope.init = false;
    }
    else {
      $scope.$broadcast('timer-resume');
    }
    $scope.timerRunning = true;  
  };

  $scope.stopTimer = function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
    $scope.timerRunning = false;
  };
}]);
```

Unfortunately, loading the page over localhost on mobile (iPhone 5S, iOS 8.1) works, but there's about a half second delay between pressing the start/stop button and the timer reacting- not exactly a pleasant user experience.

I also tried a jQuery [implementation](https://github.com/jylauril/jquery-runner) which ran faster, but still not as snappy as the same site on desktop (or the native timer, understandably).

So my question is this: is there any configuration of javascript I can do to make this run quickly? I haven't done any mobile app development, so completing this project web based would be ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the delay in the button press wasn't caused by angular at all, but by the inherent [300 ms delay](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away) added to clicks by the mobile browser.

So, by using [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)(and following the included instructions), the performance on mobile is as snappy as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not the timer, but the digest cycle for the scope is not being triggered when you change the $scope.timerRunning value.
Try doing this after you change the value:
$scope.$digest();

Comment: Interesting! That would make sense, but when I add that line to my stop and start functions, I get [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply) error about it already being in a digest loop (and no change in speed on mobile). That makes sense, because the timer is ticking pretty quickly. Good thought though.

Comment: if digest didn't work, sometimes apply would :)

try this one: 
     if(!$scope.$$phase) {
$scope.$apply();
  //$digest or $apply
}

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply

Comment: that correctly catches the error, but it still doesn't actually speed up the response time from touch to action.