# $apply already in progress error without using $apply()?

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a "$apply already in progress" angular error, but I am not using $apply directly.
This error happens rarely, and I don't have a full stack of it and no way to recreate it on my machine.

1. Is it possible to get this error without calling $apply?
2. If for instance I have one $timeout inside another $timeout, could this trigger this error (I know $timeout calls $apply)
3. What happens if I call $apply() without any expression inside, does that do anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)

Comment: Actually that thread does not answer my question, since It refers to cases where you DID call $apply() directly which I did not.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party directives that could be calling it? If so, which ones?

Comment: Using angular-mousewheel, angular-touch and angular-xeditable