# how to get selected element in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to get selected value of menu option .Actually In my demo when I click button it show menu  option I want to get the selected element text when user click any select option from the menu and hide the menu .

How to get the selected item from menu or selected text from menu .First click button it show menu item Then select any element from menu then get the element from menu.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPaOQY

```
   link:function(scope,element,attr){

                $(element).menu();
              $(element).bind('click',function(){
                  alert('--')
                  isMenuVisibles=false;
              })
```

Comment: It is not the right way to use directives in angular js.

Comment: @ben could you please tell me right way

Comment: @Jossef Harush was the fastest. I also suggest to rather set your menu options in your controller (no hardly in your view) and dynamically generate your `<li>` menu with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: thanks but what is the use of   $timeout(angular.noop) ..you also give solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives designed to integrate with 3rd party libraries (such as jquery-ui menu in your use case)

### use the proper convention

**nope -** `<ul custommenu isMenuVisible="isMenuVisible"`

**good -** `<ul custommenu is-menu-visible="isMenuVisible"`

when using a directive parameters, the case changes in the html and in the definition. [read more about it here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> #### Normalization
>
> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name
>   to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer
>   to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes. Convert
>   the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase. For example, the following
>   forms are all equivalent and match the ngBind directive:

---

### To sum up,

i would modify your snippet like this:

### http://codepen.io/Jossef/pen/eNZobv

**html**

```
  <div class="menu" ng-show="isMenuVisible">
    <ul custommenu is-menu-visible="isMenuVisible" selected-menu-item="selectedItem">
      <li class="ui-state-disabled">Aberdeen</li>
      <li>Ada</li>
      ...
```

**js**

```
app.directive('custommenu', function($timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          isMenuVisible: '=',
          selectedMenuItem: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          $(element).menu({
            select: function(event, ui) {
              scope.selectedMenuItem = ui.item.text();
              scope.isMenuVisible = false;
              $timeout(angular.noop);
            }
          });

        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: can I use $scope.$apply  there ?

Comment: @PallaviSharma. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12729122/3191896) will answer your question. basically you can replace it with `$scope.apply` but it will fail if already running and will probably cause you to debug it in the future. your choice :)

Comment: Thanks but what $timeout(angular.noop) is meaning of this line ..when we use this line

Comment: `angular.noop` is a global empty function equals to `function(){}`
you need to use it if you dealing with events coming from 3rd party integration (such as the click event of the menu)

what it does it triggers the `$apply` and it causes the scope to *refresh* with the new modifications

i strongly suggest you to read [this amazing answer and the comments ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18996042/3191896)

Comment: @PallaviSharma its `$apply` not `apply`. see this http://codepen.io/Jossef/pen/pJyBXE