# Why are these two updates no reflected in the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to understand how to properly manipulate properties via a controller.  The following code executes six updates over four seconds.  Updates two and three are not reflected in the view.  Why is this, and what do I need to do to have updates of those types affect the view?

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller"> 
    myValue: <span ng-bind="myValue"></span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Controller',  function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.myValue = "first";
    console.log($scope.myValue);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $scope.myValue = "second";  // never updates
        console.log($scope.myValue);
        $scope.$emit("my-event", "third"); // never updates
        console.log($scope.myValue);
        $interval(function() {
            $scope.$emit('my-event', "fourth");
        }, 1000, 1);
    }, 1000);

    $interval(function() {
        $scope.myValue = "fifth";
        console.log($scope.myValue);
        $interval(function() {        
            $scope.$emit("my-event", "sixth");
        }, 1000, 1);
    }, 3000, 1);

    $scope.$on('my-event', function (event, arg) {
        $scope.myValue = arg;
        console.log(arg);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9gbpddy/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I obviously wasn't clear enough in the original question, as the upvoted answer (correctly) suggests using `$timeout` rather than `setTimeout`, however the original intent was to understand *why* the updates were not being reflected in the view, and what could be done to have these types of updates (*that originate outside angular*) affect the view as was intended.

## Read the Scope guide

So whilst I chose to skip the [Scopes section](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) of the developer guide because it looked to be the most boring, it was probably the most important, and it clearly points out some items imperative to understanding how angular binds data, notably the *Scope Life Cycle* which notes;

> When the browser calls into JavaScript the code executes outside the
>   Angular execution context, which means that Angular is unaware of
>   model modifications. To properly process model modifications the
>   execution has to enter the Angular execution context using the `$apply`
>   method. Only model modifications which execute inside the `$apply`
>   method will be properly accounted for by Angular.

There's an excellent [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113029/469777) that further explains this concept.  The first setence aptly reiterates the importance of understanding scope:

> You need to be aware about how Angular works in order to understand
>   it.

## Don't just call $scope.$apply

So you start adding calls to `$scope.$apply` around the place to cater for these things that originate outside angular, but then eventually you start getting:

```
Error: $digest already in progress
```

Which means you can't call `$scope.$apply` whilst `$digest` is executing.  After which you may think, well how can I conditionally call `$scope.$apply` based on whether the `$digest` is currently running.  But, you don't need to do that...

## Just use $timeout

Hah, like the [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881419/469777), I know, but based on a different thought process I think.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18996042/469777).  `$timeout` is not just being used in place of `setTimeout`, but rather is being used (without a `delay`) to wrap any model updates that are called from outside the Scope Life Cycle, and doing so ensures no conflict with any currently processing `$digest`.

## Wrapping up

So, in the original code snippet, the second and third updates are not reflected in the view because they are performed outside the Angular execution context.  The fact that third update doesn't affect the model also means that calling events outside the execution context doesn't get you into the execution context either.

The fourth update is already wrapped inside `$interval`, which itself causes the updates that code to be run on the next digest.  Therefore, updating the code to show an example of an event outside the angular execution context that causes its updates to be shown in the view is as follows:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $timeout(function({ // start wrap
        $scope.myValue = "second";  // now this updates!
        console.log($scope.myValue);
        $scope.$emit("my-event", "third"); // now this updates!
    })); // end wrap
    console.log($scope.myValue);
    $interval(function() {
        $scope.$emit('my-event', "fourth");
    }, 1000, 1);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` to opt-in to the digest cycle. `second` won't show since the turn of the digest cycle overrides the value of `myValue`.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9gbpddy/4/

Comment: I'm using setTimeout as an example only, how can it be fixed without switching the function?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams i'm not sure what you mean - if this isn't the code that has a problem, how am i supposed to solve it?

Comment: I was just using a setTimeout as an example of a function being executed at a later stage outside the initialising of the constructor.  Had I known $timeout was a function, I would have used that instead of the $interval function in the example to make it clearer that I understand that the updates occur properly when angular functions are calling them, however I'm trying to find out how I can update the view when things are triggered outside angular... if that makes sense?

Comment: You can use `$scope.$apply` or wrap the external stuff - its hard to know exactly what is out side of angular unless you are explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `{{myValue}}` instead of a `<span>` element