# AngularJS Scope not updating in view after async call

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, scope

I am having trouble updating my scope on the front-end while making a request to an API. On the backend I can see that the value of my $scope variable is changing but this is not being reflected in the views.

Here is my controller.

```
Controllers.controller('searchCtrl', 
 function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
   $scope.$watch('search', function() {
      fetch();
   });

 $scope.search = "Sherlock Holmes";

 function fetch(){
   var query = "http://api.com/v2/search?q=" + $scope.search + "&key=[API KEY]&format=json";
    $timeout(function(){
      $http.get(query)
      .then(function(response){ 
        $scope.beers = response.data; 
        console.log($scope.beers);
      });
    });  
 }
});
```

Here is a snippet of my html

```
<div ng-if="!beers">
  Loading results...
</div>
<p>Beers: {{beers}}</p>
<div ng-if="beers.status==='success'">

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-8 .col-lg-8' ng-repeat="beer in beers.data track by $index" ng-if="beer.style">
    <h2>{{beer.name}}</h2>          
    <p>{{beer.style.description}}</p>
    <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-if="beers.status==='failure'">
  <p>No results found.</p>
</div>
```

I've tried several solutions including using **$scope.$apply();** but this just creates the common error

> Error: $digest already in progress

The following post suggested to use **$timeout** or $asyncDefault
[AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)

The code I have above uses $timeout and I have no errors but still the view is not updating.

Help appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't need the `timeout` - `$http` will trigger a `$digest` cycle - are you sure the data is coming back?

Comment: add an error handler to the request. Also check dev tools network to make sure request is succeeding and returning what is expected. Sounds  like ajax problem

Comment: Agreed that no timeout is needed for this code, and that $http should trigger a digest cycle. Does your console.log inside the $http response show $scope.beers updated?

Comment: Why a `timeout`? When the answer from the server is ready, `then` give you the data. I suggest to use a `service ` and call it from the controller, saving the result in `$scope.beers`.

Comment: To clarify the reason I was using $timeout is because other posts suggested to use $scope.$apply(). The caused the digest error and timeout is one way to sidestep this.

Comment: @peterpod - then that indicates that somehow the digest cycle is not being properly triggered, even though an apply shows one in progress. I'm curious to see jusopi's proposal makes a difference. As a side note, best practice is to make API calls from services rather than controllers. I'd put the fetch method in a service, and have the controller call the service method when the expected event occurs. Setting a watch for a variable you are going to staticly declare is not right though. Either call fetch directly, at controller instantiation, or wire it up to UI like a button click.

Comment: are you sure that your repeat is right?  you have `ng-repeat="beer in beers.data`, and in your controller you have `$scope.beers = response.data;`.  That would mean that your ng-repeat is iterating over the equivalent of `response.data.data;`.  Is that really what your response looks like, or are you doubling your `data`s?

Comment: @AndrewCavanagh thanks for looking closely at the code but believe it or not the response is structured that way.

Answer (score 13):

I you are using AngularJS 1.3+, you can try `$scope.$applyAsync()` right after `$scope.beers = response.data;` statement.

This is what Angular documentation says about `$applyAsync()`

> Schedule the invocation of $apply to occur at a later time. The actual time difference varies across browsers, but is typically around ~10 milliseconds. [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

**Update**

As others have pointed out, you should not (usually) need to trigger the digest cycle manually. Most of the times it just points to a bad design (or at least  not an AngularJS-friendly design) of your application.

Currently in the OP the `fetch` method is triggered on $watch. If instead that method was to be triggered by `ngChange`, the digest cycle should be triggered automatically.

Here is an example what such a code might look like:

**HTML**

```
// please note the "controller as" syntax would be preferred, but that is out of the scope of this question/answer
<input ng-model="search" ng-change="fetchBeers()">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function SearchController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.search = "Sherlock Holmes";

    $scope.fetchBeers = function () {
        const query = `http://api.com/v2/search?q=${$scope.search}&key=[API KEY]&format=json`;
        $http.get(query).then(response => $scope.beers = response.data);
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*As the comments suggest, you shouldn't need to use `$timeout` to trigger a digest cycle. As long as the UX that elicits the change is within the **confines** of an angular construct (e.g. controller function, service, etc.) then it should manifest within the digest cycle.*

Based on what I can infer from your post, you are probably using a search input to hit an API with results.  I'd recommend changing the logic up such that you are triggering your search on an explicit event rather than the `$watch`er.

```
<input ng-model="search" ng-change="fetch()">
```

Remove the `$watch` logic and the `$timeout` wrapper.

```
function fetch(){
    var query = "http://api.com/v2/search?q=" + $scope.search + "&key=[API KEY]&format=json";
$http.get(query)
.then(function(response){ 
    $scope.beers = response.data; 
    console.log($scope.beers);

    //it's a good habit to return your data in the promise APIs
    return $scope.beers;  
});
}
```

The reasons I make this recommendation is:

- You have finer control of how the `ng-change` callback is triggered using `ng-model-options`.  This means you can put a delay on it, you can trigger for various UX events, etc.
- You've maintained a clearer sequence of how `fetch` is called.
- You have possibly avoided performance and $digest issues.

Comment: Hey. Let me try this out! Perhaps I'm being too fancy with the watcher

Comment: I hope it works out. Generally I use `$watch` for things that aren't directly triggered by some UX (in other words, not triggered by an existing directive or other ng construct) and in directives where I need to tap into DOM events where I don't want to wire up an isolate scope, etc.

Comment: I tried you suggestion with ng-change but decided I will just be simple here and do ng-submit. Regardless even with this method the view is not updating. My consolelog prints out a new json response on each form submission but the scope variable doesn't update. I updated my post above to show my html

Comment: you need to inspect the response from your service call.  I'm guessing you're getting everything coming back as normal, you're just inspecting the wrong data?

Comment: Do you mean I may be parsing it incorrectly? The thing is disregarding whether the status is successful I put  <p>Beers: {{beers}}</p> to check if the variable is even changing. However, its just undefined the entire time as a result the top div displays with "Loading results"

Comment: I'd recommend making a plunkr/jsfiddle so we can see it in context.  Sorry we're not much help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I solved the issue but I'm not sure exactly why this changed anything. Rearranging my code on JS Fiddle I just put all my partials into the index.html file like so and the requests and scope variables updated smoothly. Is was there perhaps a controller conflict with my html above?

```
<body ng-app="beerify" ng-controller='searchCtrl'>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container"><!-- nav bar code -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <form ng-submit="fetch()">
      <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" ng-model="search" 
                 class="form-control" placeholder="Search the name of a beer" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div ng-if="!beers">
    Loading results...
  </div>
  <div ng-if="beers.status==='success'">
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-8 .col-lg-8' ng-repeat="beer in beers.data track by $index" ng-if="beer.style">
        <!-- ng-if will make sure there is some information being displayed
           for each beer -->
        <h2>{{beer.name}}</h2>
        <h3>{{beer.style.name}}</h3>
        <p>AbvMin: {{beer.abv}}</p>
        <p>AbvMax: {{beer.ibu}}</p>      
        <p>{{beer.style.description}}</p>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="beers.status==='failure'">
    <p>No results found.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```