# Angularjs value not updating

Tags: html, angularjs

I know similar questions have been asked but they don't apply to my case. I have defined some variables in my controller and display their values in a panel. My controller related to the part is like this:

```
var vm = this;
vm.wellId = "id";
vm.wellSeq = "sequence";
vm.onWellSelected = onWellSelected;
...
function onWellSelected(wells) {
    ...
    vm.wellId = wells[0]["id"];
    vm.wellSeq = wells[0]["sequence"];
    ...
}
```

and my html component is like this:

```
<div plate id="plate-layout"
    on-well-selected="vm.onWellSelected(wells)">
</div>
<ul class="list-group" style="width: 400px; overflow: auto">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{vm.wellId}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{vm.wellSeq}}</li>
</ul>
```

I checked the source and set break points in the function onWellSelected: vm.wellId and vm.wellSeq are indeed changed to the correct values after the operation, but the new value cannot be displayed. The definition of plate involves quite a number of other js files so not easy to show here, but plate itself is a directive, with support from two services. What could be the reasons? Thanks!

Comment: depends on where and how `onWellSelected()` is called. Show full context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry I'm new to Angular so took me a while to find this:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Put it after the modification part and then the value is updated on the page.

**EDIT:**

Just a follow-up: if use this: $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest(), then I'll get this error: $digest already in progress; but if I remove it, the value won't get updated. So I refer to this post here: [Prevent Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply), and now it's working fine without the error message. Hope this can help those facing the same issue.

Comment: No, that's not required. `$scope.$apply()` is redundant. Moreover since 1.2 `$scope` is not required at all to update controller fields. Use `controller as` syntax instead.
You defined the controller incorrectly. See the answer below with correct syntax.

Comment: Sorry there are a lot of files involved so I cannot show everything here, but I'm quite sure my controller should be correct. I established the link between js and html in the controller js file, instead of using ng-app and ng-controller. Now using $apply indeed gives me the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function () {
  var vm = this;
  vm.wellId = "id";
  vm.wellSeq = "sequence";

  vm.onWellSelected = function (wells) {
    vm.wellId = wells[0]["id"];
    vm.wellSeq = wells[0]["sequence"];
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <span>{{vm.wellId}}</span>
    <span>{{vm.wellSeq}}</span>
    <button ng-click="vm.onWellSelected([{id: 'new id', sequence: 'new sequence'}])">Select Well</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An explanation would be useful here.