# Jquery web cam integration in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i want to attach web cam to a div element.the way i used to do in jquery is like below,How can i attach web cam to a div using angularjs

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  
        $("#Camera").webcam({  
            width: 320,  
            height: 240,  
            mode: "save",  
            swffile: "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jscam.swf")",  
            onTick: function () { },  
            onSave: function () {  
                UploadPic();  
            },  
            onCapture: function () {  
                webcam.save("@Url.Content("~/Photo/Capture")/");  
         },  
            debug: function () { },  
            onLoad: function () { }  
        });  
    </script>  
}
```

i know i have to  create a directive for this.
doubt :weather i have to convert all jquery.webcam.js file need to change to directive or any other way is there to do it.

i tried with `<ng-Camera></ng-Camera>` available on github  but it is not supporting in IE

if any one have any help-link to do webcam Capture image accross all the browser pls update here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to rewrite all the webcam files, the only thing you have to remember is when you change something outside of Angular you have to run a `$scope.$apply()` ([or $timeout, which is safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)) so Angular knows it should run a `digest cycle` (this means after every callback such as onLoad, onTick, onSave)