# Is safeApply is best practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to work more with directives to apply a bit more best practices but I have some questions on the best way to apply a scope value from a directive.

In this [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/osbbzfts/1/), you can see if you click on the "Toggle displayMenu " button, the div is still toggled on.
If you toggle lines 7-8 in directive's code :

```
scope.yolo = function () {
    scope.ctrl.toggle(); // COMMENT ME
    //scope.ctrl.toggleApply(); // UNCOMMENT ME
};
```

to :

```
scope.yolo = function () {
    //scope.ctrl.toggle(); // COMMENT ME
    scope.ctrl.toggleApply(); // UNCOMMENT ME
};
```

the displayMenu div will toggle off.

Now, the problem is I am forced to write 2 functions, one with "$scope.$apply" and one without, and it is clearly not a smart way to do it...
unless I use safeApply like :

```
 $rootScope.safeApply = function(fn) {
        var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
        if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
            if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
                fn();
            }
        } else {
            this.$apply(fn);
        }
    };
```

Is the safeApply is the best practice ?
If not, what is the best way to accomplish what I want ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the `$$phase` is considered bad practice. From a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply/18996042#18996042) the angular devs have said that:

> For future-proofing reasons, you should not use $$phase

The recommended best practice is to either use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) or [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) which both defer the execution of the code. In essence, both functions will be executed in a new $digest cycle so you don't have to manually call $apply yourself. Most of the time you can probably use $evalAsync if you just need to update some code in a safeApply scenario.

```
scope.$evalAsync(function(scope) {
  // run the toggle function without caring if you're in the digest or not
  scope.ctrl.toggle();
});
```

You can read [this article by Ben Nadal](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm) to see how the different functions get executed in the JavaScript process.