# How to avoid $digest already in progress error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs application I have these lines of code

```
getGridPage('api/accounts/gettransactions') //$http call to server which sets the $scope
$scope.transactions = {}
```

and I'm getting $digest already in progress error.
How can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure neither of these two lines is the source of the problem.
How about showing the contents of getGridPage?

Comment: While I agree with the comment above me, check out this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply  (I don't know how to link directly to answers, sorry).  Also be sure to read the comments on it.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in `getGridPage()` you're calling `scope.$apply()` or `scope.$digest`. Get rid of that call and the error will go away.