# How to avoid use of watch to prevent directive from modifying a property in a manner I don't want

Tags: angularjs

I'm using an *old* version of timepicker, which lacks the min & max options (and which I sadly can't update at this time).  My view looks like this:

```
 <timepicker class="col-md-2" ng-model="date" hour-step="1" minute-Step="0">
```

I want to prevent timepicker from increasing/decreasing the time beyond certain values.  I currently use a watch:

*retyped instead of copy-paste, so obvious syntax errors are likely typos, sorry*

```
$scope.$watch('date', function(newVal, oldVal){
     if(newVal<minTime){
         $scope.date=minTime
         $scope.digest();
     }

     else if(newVal>maxTime){
         $scope.date=maxTime
         Rscope.digest();
     }
}
```

I needed the digests or the timePicker wouldn't reflect my adjusting the time back to my desired values.  However, I now can get a "$digest already in progress" error per this question: [AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)

However, it's also stated that this is considered an undesirable approach, and that it would be better to avoid using $watch if at all possible.

Is there a different approach beyond the $watch & $digest approach I'm using to more elegantly prevent/reset scope changes like this, that ensures that the timepicker will immediately reflect my reverting it's changes?

...yes switching away from the timepicker were using is already on the to-do list, there are other reasons I dislike it, but I'm more interested in how to handle this use case in general then a fix to this specific issue.

Comment: can't you use `ng-change` on input field instead of `$watch`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your model in `setTimout()` like below to avoid the error **$digest already in progress**

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.location3 = 'Your selected value'
                    });
}, 2000);
```

Alternatively you can also utilize `$timeout` service to achieve the same result.