# Alternative for using $scope.$digest() or $scope.$apply() in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope varible containing an array of articles (JSON objects)

```
$scope.mainArticles = [];
```

An article has these properties

```
{
 "title": "ABCD",
 "type": "XYZ" 
}
```

I Filter the scope variable `$scope.mainArticles` based on article type, using the filter method of JS.

```
$scope.mainArticles = $scope.mainArticles.filter(filterByTypeFunction);
```

But my DOM never updates even though the scope variable has changed. Is there any way I can avoid using `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()` in this scenario?

I don't wanna use them since there are plenty of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply) which advises against using them.

Comment: `$scope.mainArticles = $scope.mainArticles.filter(filterByTypeFunction);` - where is this called? Can you show more code?

Comment: Could you add fiddle/plunkr of the problem?

Comment: There is no such rule as 'don't use $digest()/$apply()' because it depends on the case if triggering a digest is required or undesired. What is your case?

Answer (score -1):

better way it is to filter you articles on the server
You don't want to load all your articles at once and then filter it

Comment: Actually I need to load all the articles up front, since by default there is no filter. So once I have all the articles on the client side, why not just filter it?

Comment: if You don't have pagination then it will be ok but with pagination your filter on the client side will be working weird because you will be filtering only one page

Comment: no matter if there is a filter or will be if user selects it, load your documents filtered (or not) and paginated from the server side, if you will have a lot of articles you will have troubles like getaways timeouts and so on