# Angular's view model is not getting updated

Tags: angularjs

Angular's view model is not getting updated when the same is updated from controller, I have tried `$scope.$apply()` with the help of `$scope.$watch` of function but AngularJS throws an error as `$digest` already in progress.

Kindly explain me if any one know the solution

Comment: [Detailed explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply) on digest cycle.

Comment: Can u post the code, change to scope vars in controllers will definitely re-render dom

Answer (score 0):

check if $diget is in progress by the following code , to prevent that error:

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  // $apply or $digest
}
```