# Is calling $scope.$digest within $scope.$on fundamentally incorrect?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have inherited some AngularJS code, and I know very little about it (the code and Angular both). The code that I inherited contains several places where `$scope.$digest` is called within a `$scope.$on` method within a controller. For example:

```
$scope.$on("ScriptEditorEnabled", function (e, enabled) {
    $scope.scriptEditorDisabled = !enabled;
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

In my context, this is causing the popular `$digest` already in progress error ([AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)). Isn't an `$on` method part of the `$scope` object, and thus, any changes to its data would be picked up automatically? If so, doesn't that mean that calling `$digest` within one (either directly or indirectly), just plain incorrect?

I've been simply removing these calls, seemingly without any loss in functionality, and the errors go away. Is there any dangers I should be aware of when doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$scope.$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) gets called in response to [`$scope.$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) or [`$scope.$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit). The `$scope.$on` should always assume that it runs inside a digest loop. Neither `$apply` nor `$digest` calls should be needed inside the `$on` handler.

Angular is pretty clear about it in the [When to use $scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide%3A-When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply()). If you dispatch events from non-angular environments, you should wrap the `$emit` or `$broadcast` call in `$apply` instead of calling it in the event handler. Example:

```
$rootScope.$apply($rootScope.$broadcast('recievedMsg', msg));
```

It's dispatcher responsibility to enter the digest loop if it knows there isn't one started already.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't an $on method part of the $scope object, and thus, any changes
>   to its data would be picked up automatically?

No. `$scope.$on` callback is triggered by `$scope.$emit` or `$scope.$broadcast`. If you inspect source code of both of them, you'll see that they don't by itself trigger `$digest` loop that checks for changes. This means that callback on `$scope.$on` can be executed from within `$digest` loop as well is outside of it. A good approach is to have a convention which defines whether the `$scope.$emit` or `$scope.$broadcast$` should be executed inside `$digest` loop or the callback within `$scope.$on` should be executed inside `$scope.$apply`. Usually, it's the code that triggers event ensures the digest loop by using `$scope.$apply()`.

A solution could be to use `$scope.$evalAsync` instead of `$scope.$apply` to avoid `digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()` error.