# ng repeat dynamic data array does not update view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-repeat, apply

Angular code:

```
$scope.activitiesmonth = [];
//get array data from server
$scope.getActivityMonth = function(){
var userID = sessionService.get('user');
var matcher = moment().format('YYYY-MM');
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url:  'getactivitymonth.php',
    data: {
        matcher : $scope.matcher,
        userID : userID
        }
}).success(function (data,status) {
    $scope.activitiesmonth = data;
});
}
//save new data to database and update array
$scope.saveActivity = function(){
var matcher = moment().format('YYYY-MM');
if($scope.activityname == null || $scope.activitytype == null){
    alert("Please complete the form!");
} else {
    var userID = sessionService.get('user');
    var activityId = parseInt($scope.activitiesmonth[$scope.activitiesmonth.length-1].activityID) + 1;
    $scope.obj = {
        0 : activityId.toString(),
        1: $scope.activityname,
        2: $scope.activitytype,
        3: $scope.momentClicked,
        4: $scope.hour,
        5: userID,
        activityFullDate : $scope.momentClicked,
        activityID : activityId.toString(),
        activityName : $scope.activityname,
        activityTime : $scope.hour,
        activitytype : $scope.activitytype,
        userID : userID
    }
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:  'postactivity.php',
        data: {
            activityname : $scope.activityname,
            activitytype : $scope.activitytype,
            date : $scope.momentClicked,
            time : $scope.hour,
            userID : userID
        }
        }).success(function (response, data) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.activitiesmonth.push($scope.obj);
            },500);
        });
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        }
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="header">

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="acadWeekHeader">{{semester}}</th>
            <th id="daysHeader" ng-repeat="day in daysInWeek">
                {{ day }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="days" ng-repeat="week in daysArray">
            <td class="acadWeek" dragula='"second-bag"'>{{weeksArray[$index]}}</td>
            <td id="{{day}}" ng-repeat="day in week track by $index" ng-class="{'greyOut':isNumber(day), 'highlight':isString(day), 'currentDay':isCurrentDay(day)}" ng-click="check(day)" dragula='"second-bag"'>
                <div ng-show="isString(day) == true" id="day">{{day}}</div>
                <div ng-show="isNumber(day) == true" id="day">{{day}}</div>
                <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="activity in activitiesmonth | filter:filterDate(day) track by $index" ng-switch="activity.activityType" dragula='"second-bag"'>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning" ng-switch-when="Quiz and Exam" id="{{ activity.activityID }}" ng-click="click()">
                        <span clas="trash" ng-click="deleteActivity(activity.activityID, $event)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <span class="activitynames">{{activity.activityName}}</span><br>
                        <span class="datetimes">{{activity.activityTime}}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger" ng-switch-when="Assignment Deadline" id="{{ activity.activityID }}" ng-click="click()">
                        <span clas="trash" ng-click="deleteActivity(activity.activityID, $event)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <span class="activitynames">{{activity.activityName}}</span><br>
                        <span class="datetimes">{{activity.activityTime}}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" ng-switch-when="CCA Activity" id="{{ activity.activityID }}" ng-click="click()">
                        <span clas="trash" ng-click="deleteActivity(activity.activityID, $event)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <span class="activitynames">{{activity.activityName}}</span><br>
                        <span class="datetimes">{{activity.activityTime}}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" ng-switch-when="Leisure Activities and Other" id="{{ activity.activityID }}" ng-click="click()">
                        <span clas="trash" ng-click="deleteActivity(activity.activityID, $event)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <span class="activitynames">{{activity.activityName}}</span><br>
                        <span class="datetimes">{{activity.activityTime}}</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I am trying to update view every time i push new data to $scope.activitiesmonth array. But it showed me "$digest already in progress" error. What should I do to update the view? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Check digest is running before you push object to $scope.activitiesmonth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply

Comment: did you try without the timeout ?

Comment: Try with `$scope.$applyAsync`

Comment: @NagaveerGowda checking if digest is running is an **anti pattern** `Don't do if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply(), it means your $scope.$apply() isn't high enough in the call stack.`

Comment: @GangadharJannu I do agree with you. Ideally you should take care while writing the code that it should not cause "$digest in progress issue". Whatever I said in the earlier is just a fix.

Comment: @Merlin yes, I have tried without the timeout it also does not work

Comment: @GangadharJannu have tried using it but still does not show anything in view :(