# How to refresh an ng-repeat list when $scope is not used?

Tags: angularjs

$scope.$apply() is mostly used when $scope is defined.
But this kind of definition does not seem to refresh the list.

HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feedCtrl.feeds"></div>
```

Controller :

```
this.feeds = response.data;
```

Comment: just reassign the `this.feeds` with new data and it will be refreshed. Also you can call `$scope.$apply()` by injecting scope into controller, so that the whole digest cycle will be ran again and update the variables

Comment: do you have some event which update the `feeds` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just **reassign the `this.feeds`** with new data and it will be refreshed.

Also you can call `$scope.$apply()` by injecting scope into controller, so that the whole digest cycle will be ran again and update the variables

**In my opinion, the issue you are facing is using `this.feeds` inside a function which will not work, because `this` refers to the `function` but not `original value`.**

So, assign `this` to a variable `vm`

**`var vm = this; and use vm.feeds = response.data`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($timeout,$scope) {

   var vm = this;
   vm.feeds = ["Feed1","Feed2","Feed3","Feed4"];
            
            $timeout(function () {
          vm.feeds = ["Changed Feed1","Changed Feed2","Changed Feed3","Changed Feed4"];
      }, 2000);
   
  })
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl as feedCtrl">
<p ng-repeat="data in feedCtrl.feeds">
 {{data}}
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

**The Code above changes the Feed after 2 seconds. Please run the above code**

[Here is a working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/trYIhBMe5LfyIH1awvqR?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been using `var controller = this;controller.feeds = response.data;`

Comment: @EdisonD'souza,  that working now? or any issue still?

Comment: I started using $scope instead of  "this" which is working fine for me.

Comment: @EdisonD'souza, okay. you can accept and vote my answer, if you find it any useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl as ctrl">
<h1 ng-repeat="x in ctrl.records">{{x}}</h1>
<button ng-click="ctrl.records=['Bananna','Grapes'];">update records</button>
```

in controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("appCtrl", function() {  this.records = ["Mango","Apple","Orange"];    });
```

Answer (score 0):

inject $scope in controller and use $scope.$apply() after retrieving data. No problem if you are using "this". ie

```
this.feeds = response.data;
$scope.$apply();
```

However don't forget to inject $scope in controller

Comment: It's bad practice to force angular for manual digest cycle. and if you need at utmost then apply safe check. `if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
}`. [Read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)