# Angular form save not working with dynamic push data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and stuck with dynamic data binding. I have four data
   fields 2 static and 2 dynamically adding after add button. When I click add
   button only two of the fields are shown on the display and remaining data
   is not populated. I might had make some mistake in data passing.
   The first two fields are static and second two are dynamic need to add as 
   user clicks. The same happens when using form.
   Will any one please help me resolve this. Thanks in advance.
   Below is my code:

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.itemsToAdd = [{
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  }];

  $scope.add = function(itemToAdd) {

    var index = $scope.itemsToAdd.indexOf(itemToAdd);

    $scope.itemsToAdd.splice(index, 1);

    $scope.items.push(angular.copy(itemToAdd))
  }

  $scope.addNew = function() {

    $scope.itemsToAdd.push({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    })
  }
});
```

View (HTML):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     {{item.regno}} {{item.section}}
    {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
  </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.regno" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.section" />
  <div ng-repeat="itemToAdd in itemsToAdd">
    <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.firstName" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.lastName" />
    <button ng-click="add(itemToAdd)">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="addNew()">Add new</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: where is regno and section coming from, in the newly added items?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/UWgIzNznpsqipKeqfozx?p=preview  its working for me

Comment: @dev8080, regno and section are static fields. firstname and last name are dynamic. Both needs to be submitted on single click.

Comment: @Ritchie, its working for only dynamic fields, what about the static fields.

Comment: Which static field

Comment: @Ritchie, that are not within ng-repeat regno and section, test in your plunker. Top two fields are not sending the data.

Comment: @NoobOwl added my answer.please go through it

Answer (score 1):

you can try after add:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: It's bad practice to force angular for manual digest cycle. and if you need at utmost then apply safe check. if(!$scope.$$phase) { //$digest or $apply } [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)

Comment: @Dmitry why you want `$scope.$apply` ? Is it non angular context?

Answer (score 0):

This section:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.regno" />
 <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.section" />
```

is outside ng-repeat and thus does not know what itemToAdd is; chnage it to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="itemToAdd in itemsToAdd">
 <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.regno" />
 <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.section" />

 <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.firstName" />
 <input type="text" ng-model="itemToAdd.lastName" />
<button ng-click="add(itemToAdd)">Add</button>
```

But this only give you empty display since you are not defining regno and section's default values anywhere. Define them in your code:

```
$scope.itemsToAdd = [{
  firstName: '',
   lastName: '',
  section: 'defaultSection',
  regno: 'defaultRegNo'
}];
```

and

```
 $scope.addNew = function() {

$scope.itemsToAdd.push({
  firstName: '',
   lastName: '',
  section: 'defaultSection',
  regno: 'defaultRegNo'
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`directives-that-create-scopes`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#directives-that-create-scopes) angular docs

> some directives, such as **ng-controller** and **ng-repeat**, create new child scopes and attach the child scope to the corresponding DOM element

In your case,

```
itemToAdd.regno & itemToAdd.section are different modals and in different scope
```

compare to `itemToAdd.firstName & itemToAdd.lastName`.

So,`regno & section` are not part of inner `itemToAdd` of ng-repeat.

Thats why,you are not able to get in your `$scope.items`

You have to add `regno & section` in `add` function

```
$scope.add = function(itemToAdd) {

    itemToAdd.regno = $scope.itemsToAdd.regno;
    itemToAdd.section = $scope.itemsToAdd.section;


    $scope.items.push(angular.copy(itemToAdd))
    console.log($scope.items);
  }
```