# WebSocket callback not fired with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I need a global application wise web-socket, which can be used by all of my controller in app.

The following code describes the my use-case where I am creating a factory to share a singleton websocket object. The interface provided are allows the controllers to send the data over socket and attach listener for incoming messages.

The problem with the following code is that I am able to send the data on socket as expected, but not able to receive data when it comes over the socket.

I have read several angular digest related solutions, but they are not working for me.

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .factory('socket', function() {
    var socketStates = ['CONNECTING', 'OPEN', 'CLOSING', 'CLOSED'];
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7070/ws");
    socket.onopen = function(event) {
      socket.send("hello");
    };

    socket.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      // I am able to see this so, it is confirmed that server is sending the data
      console.log(event);
    });

    return {
      emit: function (data) {
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      on: function(callback) {
        socket.addEventListener('message', callback);
      },
      getStatus: function() {
        var status = socket.readyState;
        return socketStates[status]
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('MyController', function(socket){
    var myctl = this;

    //This works
    socket.emit({type : "register", name: producer});

    //This doesn't work
    socket.on(function(event) {
      console.log(event);
    });
  });
```

`$rootScope.$apply(socket.addEventListener('message', callback));`

instead  of

`socket.addEventListener('message', callback);`

throws the following error

`vendor.js:5 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress(…)(anonymous function)`

Comment: Should your eventListener be reading 'onmessage'?

Comment: couldn't understand your question, yes the eventListener should be fired on onmessage

Comment: Try swapping `emit` and `socket.on` and ensure your server is sending any data

Comment: I believe the message listener doesn't exist? The onmessage event listener is what is documented on the socket docs?

Comment: @Oskar I am sure the server is sending the data, check the code I have edited the code.

Comment: @Jackthomson https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: @bruce_wayne and do you have anything in your console?

Comment: @Oskar yes if I use keep the outer block (just below the onopen ), I see messages on console, if I remove that I see nothing although I am attaching the other listener/callback.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Oski/bkhscg54/ I created a jsfiddle with your example, with wsecho it works fine...

Comment: I read your question again, so the main reason is that the digest is already in progress, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply

Answer (score 2):

The digest process is already in progress you have to check the `$$phase` and wrap your code with if statement:

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) {
  $rootScope.$apply(socket.addEventListener('message', callback));
} else {
  socket.addEventListener('message', callback);  
}
```

For more check: [AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)

Comment: can we have `$scope` inside factory ?

Comment: In theory you can, but I wouldn't recommend that, if you use `$rootScope` in your factory consider refactoring your code. `$$phase` probably works with `$rootScope` as well

Comment: It's working now, and don't understand how, becuase my code is going in to still else part. And more thing why `(!$scope.$$phase)` is considered as anti-pattern ?

Comment: @bruce_wayne I think it's prone to error, because it can create race conditions and fire many unnecessary `$apply` / `$digest` phases one after another

Comment: what's the better way to do it ?

Comment: @bruce_wayne First of all extract `$rootScope` / `$scope` from your factories/services, expose the needed functionality as API in your factories/services and call it from your controllers. Check the information flow in your app, if you're not sure if the piece of code happens in `$digest` phase or is a direct cause of `$digest` then you need to refactor, sooner or later it will blow into your face with an error hard to find. Basically, if a `$digest` is already triggered, it will check if you changed your values after is completed. If something has changed, `$digest` is fired again.

Comment: I can't do that that's the whole point of using websockets, I don't know when message will appear inside the controller from the server. So there is no way beforehand to call the $digest loop, unless I do it in factory.

Comment: @bruce_wayne Yes, but you can for instance use events in your application rather than calling `$rootScope.apply` and let the other components to decide when to call `apply` and what to do with the data

Answer (score 0):

Your `socket.on()` event is running digest cycle which is conflicting with current digest cycle.

you can use `setTimeut()` to solve this problem

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
       socket.on(function(event) {
          console.log(event);
      }); 
});
```