# AngularJS not showing data when promise resolves

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My table won't display the data it receives after a promise resolves. The data, however, is shown after a filter query is updated.

Angular:

```
let app = angular.module("tierlist", []);

app.controller("tierListController", function ($scope, $http) {


    firebase.database().ref('/Primaries/').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());

        $scope.Primaries = $.map(snapshot.val(), function (element) {
            return element;
    });
    console.log($scope.Primaries);
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container tiertab" id="Primaries">
    <table id="primariesTable" class="table table-condensed table-responsive sortable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th onclick="sortTable('primariesTable', 0)">Rank</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable('primariesTable', 1)">Weapons</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable('primariesTable', 2)">Primary DMG Type</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable('primariesTable', 3)">CC Mechanic</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable('primariesTable', 4)">MR Req</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Base or Event Rankings</th>
            <th>Suggested Builds</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="sortable" ng-repeat="primary in Primaries | filter: $ctrl.query" >
            <td>{{primary.rank}}</td>
            <td>{{primary.name}}</td>
            <td>{{primary.damage}}</td>
            <td>{{primary.cc}}</td>
            <td>{{primary.mr}}</td>
            <td>{{primary.notes}}</td>
            <td>{{primary.event}}</td>
            <td>{{primary.builds}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I believe I'm doing something wrong as far as the controller is involved. If the data is associated with the given fields, why would the data not display after resolving the promise?

Comment: `$scope.Primaries = $.map(snapshot.val()` - how are you acessing the (assumingly) jQuery object? Try logging `element` to console from within the loop and tell me what you see.

Comment: I'm accessing the Primaries array using the ng-repeat directive in the HTML code. I'm also totally sure the data is loading correctly and being assigned correctly. Running a log of Primaries inside the callback shows that Primaries is correct, however a log of Primaries outside the callback is correctly showing no data. This is further proven by the fact that the table loads correctly after the query is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $scope bound data is updated asynchronously angular doesn't update the view because it doesn't know when this is going to happen. Your data could be being updated when filtering since angular is internally triggering $scope.$digest(). You could try:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function () {
    $scope.Primaries = $.map(snapshot.val(), function (element) {
        return element;
    });
});
```

This should update the view. $evalAsync was introduced in angularjs 1.2 but you can use $scope.$apply if the version you are using is older. This post has great info on the difference between both: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23102223/7083204

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve the issue! Will check out the provided link as well.