# $scope unaccessible inside promise .then

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a promise and I need to call a function in my `$scope`. If I call the function outside the `then` it works but actually I need to call it after the promise has been resolved, inside the `then`. Unfortunately the `$scope` is unavailable at that stage

```
traverseTree(items).then(function(data){
   $scope.$apply(function () {
       $scope.myArray.push(data);
   });
});
```

I didn't find any solution to this problem, actually I don't even know what keywords to use for searching a solution online

**EDIT**

Here the stacktrace, the exception get thrown at `$scope.$apply`

[image]

`$scope` looks valorized correcly inside the `then`

Comment: please post stack trace you get, I believe its not `scope` encapsulation problem

Comment: I'm doing it... just a sec..

Comment: @Satpal $scope.$timeout is not a function

Comment: remove `$scope.$apply(function () {})`, you don't need that

Comment: why do you use scope.apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$scope` is accessible, but the issue is that you are trying to manually run digest cycle whilst it already in progress, so just remove the apply, it will be fine. You should have smth like this

```
traverseTree(items).then(function(data){
   $scope.myArray.push(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You error is, in fact, because you are trying to run a new digest cycle while another is already executing.

If you are not doing anything outside Angular's reach, you don't need to manually call the $apply, Angular automatically does it for you.

For more information, [take a look at this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply).